# TSQL Parsing string to columns by a delimeter or words

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We are selecting data from a table that stores a lot of information inside a single column. I am looking for a way to split this data into columns.

Here is an example of the raw string returned:

```
     From Display      : \\path\to\display - info Event Tag         : STR.11 Start Date        : '20130806 10:31:18'  End Date          : '20130807 18:35:52'  Delta            : 1D 08:04:34  Reason            : Machines : DownTime : Market Outage  Comment           : Market outage  Process           : ABCD  Equipment         :  Grade             : 123123  Logged By Process : ABC
```

Here is the data if I add some line breaks to view it easier.

```
From Display      : \\path\to\display - info 
Event Tag         : STR.11 
Start Date        : '20130806 10:31:18'  
End Date          : '20130807 18:35:52'  
Delta             : 1D 08:04:34  
Reason            : 
Machines : 
DownTime : Market Outage  
Comment           : Market outage  
Process           : ABCD  
Equipment         :  
Grade             : 123123  
Logged By Process : ABC
```

The number of spaces between each row label an their ':' are not always the same and some rows might not have any data on the right side as shown above.

The number of characters per each line are not consistent. in the example above 'Comment' is 'Market outage' but could be a paragraph if someone was to enter more detail.

We if we select more than one record they will each come in this format, I would like to parse each into columns. So my result would look like:

```
Column headings (from display, event tag, start date, etc..)
Record 1 ----
Record 2 ----
```

I believe that it could either be split by 'columnname%:' or '  :'.

Comment: If you're really getting that raw output, then there's no way to separate it. How are we suppose to know when one column ends, and the other begins? I feel we're missing some information. Maybe pivot is the way you want to go but you'd need to better explain what's happening here and how the data looks in the table.

Comment: Is the number of colons consistent?

Comment: The program used has a form which stores everything all together in one column when submitted, its a 3rd party application which we cannot change. However the number of columns should always be the same.

Comment: Is column name always same?

Comment: So does your table look basically like the section with the line breaks in it? With only one column, each row containing each of those lines of information?

Comment: The column names will always be they same, but there is sometimes a little bit of an inconsistency with the amount of spaces. One example might be `'From Display      :'` and the next `'From Display     :'` but there should always be at least 2 spaces in between the label and colon.

Comment: @KevinDeVoe the data comes in the single line format shown above. I just added the line breaks so you can see the labels on the left and the data on the right separated by a colon. The data comes without any line breaks or carriage returns.

Comment: Ok! if your column name is same then you can do it. I will give you answer.

Comment: @Xainey If it's coming in one string you're going to have a long query with this. You'll have to do splits with hard coded strings. Then trim everywhere. Put this into a temp table, then do a pivot. (Read more on pivots http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx). Then hope the label fields never change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write little dirty code for this. I don't see any other option. 
If you know the columns name, you should create a temporary table first.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp2 (column_name VARCHAR(500))
INSERT INTO #temp2
SELECT      'From Display'        UNION ALL
SELECT       'Event Tag'        UNION ALL
SELECT       'Start Date'        UNION ALL
SELECT       'End Date'        UNION ALL
SELECT       'Delta'
```

Then you need to modify you input string. I will add & sign before each column name, you can add and specific character or string.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @column VARCHAR(200)
SET @string = 'From Display      : \path\to\display - info Event Tag         : STR.11 Start Date        : ''20130806 10:31:18''  End Date          : ''20130807 18:35:52''  Delta            : 1D 08:04:34'
```

DECLARE some_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT column_name
FROM   #temp2

OPEN some_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor
INTO @column 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @string  = REPLACE(@string, @column, '&' + @column)
    FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor
    INTO @column
END
CLOSE some_cursor
DEALLOCATE some_cursor

/
Then you can perform simple parsing

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(item, 0, CHARINDEX(':', item)), SUBSTRING(item, CHARINDEX(':', item) + 1, LEN(item)) from dbo.fnasplit(@string, '&')
```

Result will be like -

```
column_name          column_vaue
From Display         \\path\to\display - info
Event Tag            STR.11
Start Date           '20130806 10:31:18'
End Date             '20130807 18:35:52'
Delta                1D 08:04:34
```

After this you can use it as you like. Hope it works.

Comment: I get an invalid object name on `dbo.fnasplit` is this a function that needs to be added in?

Comment: Use any one of the splitting function from [here](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup)

Comment: Having a little trouble getting one of those functions to work, they all return ints. Then `item` isnt defined in your last query, is that the same as @string.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/85943/Split-function) split function works for all data. Make sure to change `Returns @Tbl_IDs Table (ID Varchar(500)) As` to `Returns @Tbl_IDs Table (item Varchar(500)) As` in function.

Comment: item should be the column name of the table returned by function. So make the above change in function.

Comment: Getting really close now. Here are the queries I'm using http://pastebin.com/vaEuF1aS And the result set im getting back
http://screencast.com/t/mQhQlA8EQu seems to be adding extra blank rows.

Comment: The function splits on each ampersand but the string passed has multiple. '&&&&&From Display      : \path\to\display - info'

Comment: INSERT the output of the select statement to temp table using `select...into...from` and write another select statement filtering blank values.

Comment: I have created a [sqlfiddlde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5626b8/2/0) for your reference. Please check it. it is working.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got everything working perfectly. Couldn't have done it without your help.